# Best way to generate thumbnails for media files(music, image, video) on Android 7.0+

Tags: java, android

Beginner here, currently made a class for fetching thumbnails for different media types audio, image etc existing on internal/sd card storage. What I want is I provide the String path through function and in return I get base64 encoded string of that image. From what I've seen is that:

```
private String getThumb(Uri uri){
        Bitmap img = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath()), THUMB_SIZE, THUMB_SIZE) ;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
        boolean success = img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, THUMB_SIZE, output) ;
        byte[] byteArray = output.toByteArray() ;
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT) ;
}
```

but it's returning following error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

other functions like createImage/createVideo thumbnail requires Android api level 29.
Also, if above code can be fixed then can it be used for video files also or different approach for video files ? And I only want Base64 string at the end of function, no layout mapping/drawables.

Comment: Add this code: `if (img==null) return null;` before you try to compress a null bitmap. You forgot that extractThumbnail() could return null?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile() is for images only. Not for 'different media types'.

Comment: ok thanks, for the suggestion I will chnage my code